# Create TFS Bug fails validation with InvalidNotOldValue

Tags: tfs

I'm creating a new WIT of type Bug, setting a custom field "External ID" which is read-only.

When I call `wit.Validate()` it's failing on this field with `InvalidNotOldValue`:

```
Validation error:
Field:External ID
Old value:
New value:INC0172473
Status: InvalidNotOldValue
```

I would expect a new WIT to validate with an empty old value, even if it's read only.

Is there something I've misconfigured in the WIT  TFS, or do I need to do something special before calling `WorkItem.Validate()`?

Similar thread over here on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/868ab402-abdf-443e-a8e1-e70bc5beca19/create-tfs-bug-fails-validation-with-invalidnotoldvalue).

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the "Read-Only" rule for "Bug", since it is read only, you cannot update the value of it even you are create a new work item.

So you need to update the rule to work around it. For example, when you create a new work item, the Title field must be changed. So you can remove the "Read-Only" rule for "External ID" and add a "WHENNOTCHANGED" rule for it. Set the "Field Condition" to "System.Title" and "Rules" to "READONLY" for "WHENNOTCHANGED" rule. Now this will allow you to pass the work item validate and set the External ID when create the work item.

Comment: Needs more upvotes. I had a "<READONLY not="[global]\Project Collection Administrators" />" entry in FIELD definition. When I removed that, I got rid of this exception, and modified the rule as per our needs. Thank you, Eddie!

Answer (score 1):

The error caused by the work item is not valid successfully. And you can check the links below for more information about validating your work items: http://bartwullems.blogspot.in/2012/04/tf237124-work-item-is-not-ready-to-save.html

Comment: It obviously is invalid. My question is specifically about WHY, given the ArrayList returned by `Validate()` is not specific enough.Your answer basically says "it doesn't work because it's broken". I was able to work around it by using `WorkItemStoreFlags.BypassRules`. However, I don't know if it's because its a readonly field, or permissions, or something else. The validation simply doesn't help.

Comment: I posted the same question on MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/868ab402-abdf-443e-a8e1-e70bc5beca19/create-tfs-bug-fails-validation-with-invalidnotoldvalue

Comment: The account that the process is running under must belong to the Project Collection Service Accounts group.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the error occurs when someone else changes the status of the request. 
That somehow 'locks' the data you submitted, displaying the (very unclear) error.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely, that SQL Server optimistic locking is an underlying error for this, when users changes state of workitem simultaneously.
TF401320 ReadOnly AllowsOldValue InvalidNotOldValue